# Reload or restart PHP Ratchet server automatically on code change

Tags: php, docker, ratchet

I run the php ratchet hello world example from http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world in a docker container and it is working as excepted.

Any idear how i can automatically restart the ratchet server after code change, so that i dont have to manually restart the docker container or the script?

Does PHP have a function to automatically reload all included php files?

In the Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["php", "/var/www/html/api.php"]
```

api.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include str_replace("\\", "/", $class_name) . '.php';
});

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())), 7000);
$server->run();
```

Chat.php:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

I am using NetBeans 12.6, Docker for Windows 4.3.1 and PHP 8.0